# I have a query in SQL Server, it takes much time to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

PFB my query plan

[image]

My Query output

I need to get all the team members details based on all the Assigned/Active rounds

[image]

I want to optimize my query. PFB my query.

```
SELECT Ass.strassociatename, 
       Ass.strphotolink, 
       team.strteamname, 
       team.strteamlogo, 
       edu.streducationalinstitute, 
       rounds.strroundname 
FROM   ccs_vas_tbl_associates Ass, 
       ccs_vas_tbl_teams team, 
       ccs_vas_tbl_educationalinstitutes edu, 
       ccs_vas_tbl_rounds rounds, 
       ccs_vas_tbl_roundassignment roundass 
WHERE  team.iteamid = 64 
       AND ass.iteamid = team.iteamid 
       AND team.ieducationalinstituteid = edu.iinstituteid 
       AND Ass.icompetitionid = rounds.icompetitionid 
       AND roundass.strroundstatus = 'Assigned' 
       AND roundass.iroundid = rounds.iroundid 
       AND roundass.iteamid = team.iteamid
```

Comment: Can you post the query plan too?

Comment: how many records in each tables and had index being added?

Comment: Check if the primary keys exist on quered tables. The query itself seems fine.

Comment: Yeah. Check indices. Publish query plan. Oh, buy hardware. THere is only so much you can do with a non-optimal data schema (yours seems t obe like that) and inappropriate hardware.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try this

```
SELECT Ass.strassociatename, 
       Ass.strphotolink, 
       team.strteamname, 
       team.strteamlogo, 
       edu.streducationalinstitute, 
       rounds.strroundname 
FROM   ccs_vas_tbl_associates Ass 
       JOIN ccs_vas_tbl_teams team ON ass.iteamid = team.iteamid 
       JOIN ccs_vas_tbl_educationalinstitutes edu ON team.ieducationalinstituteid = edu.iinstituteid
       JOIN ccs_vas_tbl_rounds rounds ON Ass.icompetitionid = rounds.icompetitionid 
       JOIN ccs_vas_tbl_roundassignment roundass ON roundass.iroundid = rounds.iroundid AND roundass.iteamid = team.iteamid 
WHERE  team.iteamid = 64 AND roundass.strroundstatus = 'Assigned'
```

Comment: New join syntax is nice, but calculatory identical.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try `UPDATE STATISTICS`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187348.aspx